# PHP read a file and store the informations in variables

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents, file-read

Is there any way to read a text file and store the information to variables?

My file.txt is like,

```
Timestamp 1343872162
No.of tall 2
No.of long 5
tall1 171
tall2 172
long1 170
long2 168
long3 168
long4 166
long5 166
```

That is, I have to retrieve these values from that file as $time=1343872162, $tall1=171, $tall2=172,$long1=170 etc.
Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyouitried.com/)

Comment: Try php INI file http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: I have options to read the file like, file_get_contents and fread. But I don't know how can I store the information into variables. Is there any way to search a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        list( $key, $value ) = explode( ' ', trim($buffer) );
        $$key = $value; //Double $$ to set a var with the string name in $key
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets() to read a file line per line.

See : [PHP fgets() Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: This doesn't answer how to store the different parts as variables.

Comment: You will need to parse the file and use dynamic variables (also called variable variables)